# configure akka debugging

Tags: scala, actor, akka

Using Akka 1.0 I cannot stop stdout-debug-output although I have set the event-handler-level to ERROR in my akka.conf which is definetely being read correctly.

My sys-out is polluted with these messages:

```
[akka:event-driven:dispatcher:global-3] DEBUG akka.actor.Actor$ - Scheduling timeout for Actor[pkg.Caller]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka 1.0 doesn't use event handler: https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/v1.0/config/akka-reference.conf

You need to change your logback config.